# How to use ajax for login form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am currently creating a login form in PHP PDO and I am using ajax to display the relevant messages on screen, e.g.

```
"Logging in..."
"Some input fields are empty"
"Your username is required"
"Your password is required"
```

Validation such as checking if input fields are empty is working fine along with when login credentials appear to be incorrect however when I login with correct credentials I just get message `"Logging in..."` and nothing happens, I don't even think it sets the session. I have also added a token to prevent CSRF and was just wondering if i'm using it correctly.

I'm unsure of what is causing my code not to proceed with logging in.

my ajax script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var submitButton = $("#btn-login");


    submitButton.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get input field values of the contact form
        var loginFormInputs = $('#login-form :input'),
            userName = $('#txt_uname_email').val(),
            userPassword = $('#txt_password').val(),
            token = $('#token').val(),
            alertMessage = $('#login-alert-message');

        // Disable Inputs and display a loading message
        alertMessage.html('<p style="opacity: 1"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin text-success"></i> Logging in..</p>');
        submitButton.html('<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
        loginFormInputs.prop("disabled", true);

        // Data to be sent to server
        var post_data = {
            'form': 'loginForm',
            'userName': userName,
            'userPassword': userPassword,
            'token': token
        };

        // Ajax post data to server
        $.post('./api', post_data, function (response) {


            // Load jsn data from server and output message
            if (response.type === 'error') {

                alertMessage.html('<p><i class="fa-lg far fa-times-circle text-danger"></i> ' + response.text + '</p>');
                submitButton.html('Login');
                loginFormInputs.prop("disabled", false);

            } else {

                alertMessage.html('<p><i class="fa-lg far fa-check-circle text-success"></i> ' + response.text + '</p>');
                submitButton.html('Login');
                window.location = "dashboard";

            }

        }, 'json');

    });

});
</script>
```

My login function `(class.user.php)` which is used in `api.php`:

```
public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `settings` LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute();
        $mainten=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass, status FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) 
        {
            if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
            {
                session_regenerate_id(false);
                return ["correctPass"=>true, "banned"=> ($userRow['status']== 1) ? true : false, "maintenance"=> ($mainten["maintenance"]== 1) ? true : false];

            }
            else
            {
                return ["correctPass"=>false];
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

api.php:

```
 //include class.user.php here and set $login = new USER();
//set $uname, $umail, $upass, $token vars here


    if( $_POST && $_POST["form"] === 'loginForm' ) {



        // Use PHP To Detect An Ajax Request code is here

        // Checking if the $_POST vars well provided, Exit if there is one missing code is here


        // PHP validation for the fields required code is here

        $validation = $login->doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass);
        if($validation["correctPass"]){
            if($validation["maintenance"]){
                if (!in_array($uname, array('admin'))){
                    $output = json_encode(
                        array(
                            'type' => 'error',
                            'text' => 'Website under maintenance.'
                        ));
                    die($output);
                }
            }
            if($validation["banned"]){
                $output = json_encode(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'error',
                        'text' => 'User has been banned.'
                    ));
                die($output);
            }else{
                if(Token::check($_POST['token'])) {
                $stmtt = $login->runQuery("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
                $stmtt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
                $userRow=$stmtt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                      $output = json_encode(
                array(
                    'type' => 'message',
                    'text' => 'Logged in successfully.'
                ));

                die($output);
                //$success = "Logged in successfully, redirecting..";
                //header( "refresh:3;url=ab" );
                //$login->redirect('dashboard');
                } else {
                    $output = json_encode(
                        array(
                            'type' => 'error',
                            'text' => 'Unexpected error occured.'
                        ));
                    die($output);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $output = json_encode(
                array(
                    'type' => 'error',
                    'text' => 'Incorrect username or password.'
                ));
            die($output);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please limit your question to the bits you are facing trouble with. Try to simplify your question and only show relevant code snippets